# Passing multiple variable with axios to controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, axios

I'm trying to insert a lecture id a students table. I need to pass the student's id as well as the lecture's to the controller. I'm using axios to post 2 parameters to the controller. My codes not working, did i do it wrong? New in Laravel. thanks

**Vue Component**

```
<a href="" @click="setLectureFK(student.student_id)"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></a>


<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
        student:'',
        lecture_id:this.$route.params.id,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        setLectureFK($student_id){
             axios.post('/api/internship/setLecture/'+$lecture_id,'/'+$student_id);
        }
    },
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function setLecture($lecture,$student)
{
    $student = student::findOrFail($student);
    $student->lecture_id_FK = $lecture;
    $student->save();
}
```

**API.PHP**

```
Route::post('internship/setLecture/{lecture}/{student}', 'API\InternshipController@setLecture')->name('internship.setLecture');
```

Comment: What is your problem then?

Comment: @ashokpoudel its not working. i made mistakes i think.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is the syntax error in your vue component .
In this line

```
axios.post('/api/internship/setLecture/'+$lecture_id,'/'+$student_id);
```

You have put the comma instead of + it should be like this

```
 axios.post('/api/internship/setLecture/'+$lecture_id+'/'+$student_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Vue Component**

```
<a href="" @click="setLectureFK(student.student_id)"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></a>


<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
        student:'',
        lecture_id:this.$route.params.id,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        setLectureFK(student_id){
             axios.post('/api/internship/setLecture',{student_id:student_id,lecture_id:this.lecture_id});
        }
    },
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function setLecture(Request $request)
{
    $student = student::findOrFail($request->student_id);
    $student->lecture_id_FK = $request->lecture_id;
    $student->save();
}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::post('internship/setLecture', 'API\InternshipController@setLecture')->name('internship.setLecture');
```